# Normality of Champernowne Constant

Tags: probability

let $x= 0.1234567891011121314\ldots$

Let $N(k,n)$ be the number of occurence of the digit $k$ ($0 \leq k \leq 9$) in the first $n$ decimals of $x$.

If  $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {N(k, n)}{n}$ exists then that limit is called the frequency of $k$ (in base $10$).

If all digits have frequency $1/10$ then the number is said to be simply normal. It is known that $x$ is simply normal (and even normal which is stronger).

However I don't understand why it is true, as it seems to me that $\frac {N(k, n)}{n}$ has no limit. 
Indeed I would say that when $n$ is equal to $9$, or to $189$, or to $2889$ and so on (hope you see the pattern here, basically when the decimal development reaches number $9$, $99$, $999$, etc.), then $\frac {N(k, n)}{n}=1/10$ for all $k$ (or at least very close, and maybe $0$ is a bit under that).

But right after those point of equality, $N(1,n)$ increases considerably up to around $30\%$ frequency.

How can I see that the sequence actually converges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the run after $99,999,999$ does not increase the fraction of $1$'s toward $30\%$.  You are thinking of [Benford's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law), where the fraction of numbers starting with $1$ increases to $50\%$.  The large number of other digits in the numbers dilutes this. When we get to $99,999,999$ we have used $9+2\cdot 90 + 3\cdot 900 +\dots +8 \cdot 90,000,000=788,888,889$ digits and $0.1$ of them are $1$'s.  By the time we get to $199,999,999$ we have used $900,000,000$ more of which $110,000,000$ are $1$'s.  The fraction has risen to about $\frac {188}{1688} \approx 0.111$  As the numbers get larger the deviations get smaller yet.

Comment: I see, I see. That makes perfect sense now. I understood, thanks!